# Не вызывается метод в forms (c#), ошибка Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий формальному параметру uri из Form1.Set(Uri, Form1.Style)

Tags: c#, .net

Я новичок в .net, раньше работал с методами в c#, но с этим сталкиваюсь впервые. Ошибка: Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий формальному параметру uri из Form1.Set(Uri, Form1.Style).
Метод надо вызывать в начале запуска программы (я вызываю в Form1()).
Вот сам метод и способ вызова:

```
public static void Set(Uri uri, Style style)
      {
          System.IO.Stream s = new System.Net.WebClient().OpenRead(uri.ToString());

          System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
          string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "wallpaper.bmp");
          img.Save(tempPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

          RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
          if (style == Style.Stretched)
          {
              key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 2.ToString());
              key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
          }

          if (style == Style.Centered)
          {
              key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
              key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
          }

          if (style == Style.Tiled)
          {
              key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
              key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 1.ToString());
          }

          SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
              0,
              tempPath,
              SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
      } //сам метод
  
public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          Set();//вызов

      }
```

Comment: Set(new Uri("http://www.mysite.ru/"), Style.Centered);

Comment: метод определен с двумя параметрами public static void Set(Uri uri, Style style),
а вызывается Set(), т.е. без них, поэтому и ругается компилятор.